# With Nginx proxying to Apache, real hostname is lost

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, hostname

I have a situation with a number of websites sharing a single IP address.  I have nginx accepting requests and passing them on to Apache, which actually serves the sites.  I know that Apache isn't really needed here, but it's set up this way for historical reasons and I'd rather not change it if I don't have to.

The way things are set up, nginx accepts a request for example.com and passes it on to Apache like so:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8100;
    }
}
```

In httpd.conf, we have

```
<VirtualHost localhost:8100>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    Options Indexes
    DocumentRoot /export/sites/example/live
    ServerAdmin info@example.net
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything has worked fine up to now, but I've added a PHP script (not my own) to the site and it is not able to get the correct hostname.  Either $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] and/or $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] are returning localhost:8100 instead of example.com.

Is it possible to set this up so that PHP will get the right hostname?

Comment: Something like `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` should do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, it sends the host spec from the `proxy_pass` line.  You can override this by throwing this config in there, forcing the `Host:` header to contain the same as sent by the client:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to change nginx thus:

```
   location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8100;
    }
```

Then modify /etc/hosts so www.example.com and example.com both point to 127.0.0.1 (internally). But Shane's answer is better, of course.

Comment: Why make it complicated when the problem can be solved with Shane's one liner. Keep it simple.

Comment: Of course, but I posted this anyway because this approach works for any proxy and Janine hadn't tested the other answer yet.